# Can I restor backup from Exchange server 2003 after server hardware down to New Exchange server 2010

Tags: exchange-2010, exchange-2003

I had a server fail. It was a Domain Controller and Exchange server running Windows Server 2003 and Exchange 2003. I have a backup of the server.

I've installed a new server as a replacement and installed Exchange 2010. How can I restore my 2003 backups to my new 2010 server?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot, you will need to bring up an Exchange 2003 environment and perform the proper migration. The database format is completely different, and won't simply restore to a 2010 environment.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchange2010/thread/bb9a5a3c-119a-4d66-9b1e-2bfc1028cb98/

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124008%28EXCHG.140%29.aspx

Comment: Also, if it was your only Domain Controller, you have a long day ahead of you. How many clients?